# Apache Showing Default page VHOST Page

Tags: apache, webserver

I've added some sites through virtual host like this, I have also specified their document route. I added all the content there, but for some reason when I visit the site through the browser the Apache default page is showing up.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mydomain/public_html"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain/error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

If anyone has any clue what's wrong, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ServerName is mydomain.com, but I assume you're trying to connect to it typing "`localhost`" on your browser. This way apache will use the default vhost instead of yours, which is probably defined on `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/default`.

What you can do is set mydomain.com to point to localhost. On Linux edit the `/etc/hosts` file adding the following line:

```
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your virtual host's configuration file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, you must create a symlink to it at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, like this:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/mydomain.com /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf
```

Notice that the extension of the symlink at `sites-enabled` is `.conf`. In my case, that was required as it's explained in the main configuration file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
```

The last two lines explain that only files at `sites-enabled` with `.conf` extension are loaded.