# wordpress website issue with apache virtualhost / incorrect settings?

Tags: wordpress, apache, debian, virtualhost

I am having some issues with setting up the virtual host settings, I guess...

I am using a domain registered at freenom(dot)com and redirected the domain name to my private VPS IP address
[DNS setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYZMM.png)

however entering the website url in firefox will show blank page and in chrome apache "It works!" default page

this is a conf file content in "sites-available"

[virtualhost_conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkkyc.png)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jaggiemccool@gmail.com
    ServerName eiga4u.ga
    ServerAlias www.eiga4u.ga

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I am quite confused of the wordpress directory location, maybe that could be the problem?
the wordpress folder location is in

/var/www/html/wordpress
[location_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upwqM.png)

I have changed the wordpress "general settings" to modify the site URL...to delete the "/wordpress"

[general settings_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Alf.png)

so if I enter just IP address it works...
but I cannot figure out what to change to view the website just by the domain name

I have also inserted a index.php file in 
/var/www/html
as well as in the wordpress folder
/var/www/html/wordpress

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
?>
```

tried to edit hosts file in /etc

```
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 eiga4u.ga
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
this line contains IP address and password
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Comment: It's working in a browser but not the other? The server is working or it is not. Is it still working in chrome?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150610/apache-showing-default-page-vhost-page

Comment: @MadeInDreams just entering the IP address, I am not sure why it does not work with the domain...in chrome it only shows the apache default page

Comment: @MadeInDreams    so i tried to edit the hosts in /etc                            ff02::1  ip6-allnodes
ff02::2  ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 eiga4u.ga
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
this line is showing my IP address and password
::1  localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

Comment: Are you sure you are working with the right config files? Its your virtual host that is not picking up. Whats the url you type in ?

Comment: @MadeInDreams VPS IP address is 104.223.41.173...but I am not sure about the config files...maybe some mistake? I am not sure how to source the issue

Comment: Did you run a2ensite?  Is the vhost in sites-enabled or only in sites-available?

Comment: @Tom ~# a2ensite wordpress
Site wordpress already enabled